# Get typeof type from type with classes

Tags: typescript

Currently I have 2 types like this:

```
export type Component = AComponent| BComponent| CComponent;
export type ComponentType= typeof AComponent| typeof BComponent| typeof CComponent;
```

Instead of duplicating code like this, is there a way to write my components once, and get two types similar to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `InstanceType` on the `ComponentType` union (Assuming `*Component` are classes). `InstanceType` is distributive, so you will get the same union as `Component`

```
export type ComponentType= typeof AComponent| typeof BComponent| typeof CComponent;
export type Component =InstanceType<ComponentType> // AComponent | BComponent | CComponent
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCDCB7AtgB0QOwKYYC7QG9owBCALmgwFdkAjLAJ2gF8AoUSGAISTUx1xFa5SjXpM2HKNHi902PIWjAR1OoxassAD3QN8uAJ6osMlPIEAVY1gC80IycQAzOHP54APg5svoPcw9cb0csP1lAhVwAbi1dRH0fEzM+KOhbAEkMCFwwDGAsaxMAHncooqwAPmgAehq3SIFobwDUpu8ItrwgA)